# Elastic Search, is it possible to get the index of a specific document in a search result set?

Tags: elasticsearch

I know the id of a specific document I want to show in my result set, but I don't know which page of the results it will be on.  Is it possible with elastic search to tell it to return the page that a specific document is on?

My guess is this is not possible.  My current approach is to run the query once loading just the documents ids and return a very large (all) result set for the query.  I find the id in this list, then I run the query again loading all of the data I want to show on the page.  I'd prefer not to run the query twice if I can avoid it.

Comment: what's your usecase? I'm asking, because if you just want the document fiven a specific id, you just filter by the id. But I believe this is not want you want?

Comment: I have a set of search parameters and a specific document id that was viewed.  I want to generate a link you can send to someone else to bring up the same search, which should have the same document in it, only the index of that document in the result set may have changed enough to push it to a new page.  I want to load the page that has the document id I specify even if it does change page for those search parameters.

Comment: hmm, that's hard indeed. Don't see another way than you describe.

Answer (score 2):

I am using JAVA API and I am getting the index, type, id and source as follows.

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch().execute().actionGet();
SearchHit[] documents = response.getHits().getHits();
for(SearchHit document : documents)
{
    System.out.println("document index :: " + document.getIndex());
    System.out.println("document type :: " + document.getType());
    System.out.println("document id :: " + document.getId());
    System.out.println("document source JSON :: " + document.getSourceAsString());      
}
```

Comment: I meant the index in the result set for a particular search, like a query that you ask it "where in the result set does this document id for this specific search" and it returns something like "77" if that documents score is 77th best overall for the specified search.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced quite similar challenge.
We have to figure out what's the clip position in some list.

It works with assumption that we sort by `score` and by document `id`.
Without sorting by `id` or anything else as second sorting rule it would not work this way.

Here's a PHP code overview of our's solution:

```
$clipScore = $this->getScore($clip);
$lowestPossibleHigherScore = $this->getLowestPossibleHigherScore($clipScore);

$countHigherScore = $this->countClipsWithMinScore($lowestPossibleHigherScore);
$countSameScoreAndHigherId = $this->countClipsWithMinScore($clipScore, $clip->getId());
$countHigherScoreAndHigherId = $countHigherScore;
if ($countHigherScore > 0) {
    $countHigherScoreAndHigherId = $this->countClipsWithMinScore($lowestPossibleHigherScore, $clip->getId());
}

$position = $countHigherScore + ($countSameScoreAndHigherId - $countHigherScoreAndHigherId);

return $position;
```

And here are some notes why this works ;)

```
/**
 * Considered test cases =D
 * 
 * | Position   | Score  | ID   |
 * | 0          | 4.0    | 3    | 
 * | 1          | 3.2    | 1    | 
 * | 2          | 3.1    | 6    | 
 * | 3          | 2.5    | 5    | 
 * | 4          | 2.5    | 4    | 
 * | 5          | 2.5    | 2    | 
 * | 6          | 1.2    | 7    | 
 * 
 * findPosition(ID = 4)
 * 
 * countAllMinScore(2.501) = 3 (A) // so it's best position is 3 (4th place)
 * countAllMinScoreAndBiggerId(2.5, 4) = 2 (C) // "two" of same score and higher ID
 * countAllMinScoreAndBiggerId(2.501, 4) = 1 (D) // "one" of higher score and higher ID
 * 
 * $position (how to get "4"?) = 3 (A) + 1 (C - D) ???  YES !!!!
 * 
 * // next case
 * findPosition(ID = 5)
 *
 * countAllMinScore(2.501) = 3 (A) 
 * countAllMinScoreAndBiggerId(2.5, 5) = 1 (C) 
 * countAllMinScoreAndBiggerId(2.501, 5) = 1 (D) 
 *
 * $position (how to get "3"?) = 3 (A) + 0 (C - D) = 3 ??? YES !!!!
 * 
 * // next case
 * findPosition(ID = 2)
 *
 * countAllMinScore(2.501) = 3 (A)
 * countAllMinScoreAndBiggerId(2.5, 2) = 5 (C)
 * countAllMinScoreAndBiggerId(2.501, 2) = 3 (D)
 *
 * $position (how to get "5"?) = 3 (A) + 2 (C - D) = 5 ??? YES !!!!
 *
 * /// next case
 * findPosition(ID = 3)
 *
 * countAllMinScore(4.001) = 0 (A)
 * countAllMinScoreAndBiggerId(4.0, 3) = 0 (C)
 * countAllMinScoreAndBiggerId(4.001, 3) = 0 (D)
 *
 * $position (how to get "0"?) = 0 (A) + 0 (C - D) = 0 ??? YES !!!!
 * 
 * /// next case
 * findPosition(ID = 7)
 *
 * countAllMinScore(1.201) = 6 (A)
 * countAllMinScoreAndBiggerId(1.2, 7) = 0 (C)
 * countAllMinScoreAndBiggerId(1.201, 7) = 0 (D)
 *
 * $position (how to get "6"?) = 6 (A) + 0 (C - D) = 6 ??? YES !!!!
 *
 *
 * /// next case
 *
 * | Position   | Score  | ID   |
 * | 0          | 4.0    | 3    |
 * | 1          | 4.0    | 1    |
 * | 2          | 3.1    | 6    |
 * | 3          | 2.5    | 5    |
 * | 4          | 2.5    | 4    |
 * | 5          | 2.5    | 2    |
 * | 6          | 1.2    | 7    |
 *
 * findPosition(ID = 3)
 *
 * countAllMinScore(4.001) = 0 (A)
 * countAllMinScoreAndBiggerId(4.0, 3) = 0 (C)
 * countAllMinScoreAndBiggerId(4.001, 3) = 0 (D)
 *
 * $position (how to get "0"?) = 0 (A) + 0 (C - D) = 0 ??? YES !!!!
 *
 * /// next case
 * findPosition(ID = 1)
 *
 * countAllMinScore(4.001) = 0 (A)
 * countAllMinScoreAndBiggerId(4.0, 1) = 1 (C)
 * countAllMinScoreAndBiggerId(4.001, 1) = 0 (D)
 *
 * $position (how to get "1"?) = 0 (A) + 1 (C - D) = 1 ??? YES !!!!
 */
```