# Get page number for an item in ElasticSearch results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I have an alphabetized index of people. My goal is to find what page of that index a person is listed on. For instance, "Tim Curry" might be listed on page 5 of the  "T" section. Currently I'm getting the page number with ActiveRecord; Elasticsearch results are 20 per page, so I can work out the page number based on the index. But it seems wiser to get the page number directly from Elasticsearch if at all possible to ensure that I'm getting the right page. Is there a way to get this data from ES?

```
def page_index
  letter= self.name[0].downcase
  index=Person.where("lower(name) like?", "#{letter}%").order("lower(name)").pluck(:id).index(self.id)
  page=index/20 + 1
end
```

Comment: Could you please explain your use case?

Comment: I'm linking instances of the person mentioned elsewhere in the site to this page.

Comment: Alright, I'm not sure exactly what you need, so my answer is wishy washy at best. However finding page is best done the way you are already doing it. There's a similar but not identical issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824016/elastic-search-is-it-possible-to-get-the-index-of-a-specific-document-in-a-sear)

Answer (score 1):

This functionality does not come bundled with ElasticSearch. Using the results per page and index is the correct approach if that is the functionality you are looking for.

Since it's not clear exactly which document you need, or what the overall UX you are trying to achieve is, I would keep in mind you can always search your index(ces) for a specific document via various mean (filtered query  term on name if you need "Tim Curry", id or _uid etc.).

Also ES is a full-text based search client, finding one Object and it's properties might be better served via a database call.

Again this is slightly heresay, as I don't know what exactly you need or are trying to achieve overall, however finding the page of a specific result in your set of returned results is best down via accessing index in your results and simple math.

Comment: Thanks. I'll just keep on keeping on with what I'm doing. I'll just need to make sure the index stays up to date.